# How to display records in a JTable from an arraylist .TXT file in java MVC?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, arraylist, jtable

Currently, this is my main screen:
([image: Main Screen])
I have 2 files: “patient.txt” and “treatment.txt” which hold records of multiple patients and treatments.

What I’m trying to do is to display all of those records in a nice JTable whenever I click “Display Treatments” or “Display Patients”, in a screen like so:
[image]

I am using an MVC model for this Hospital Management System (with HMSGUIModel.java, HMSGUIView.java, HMSGUIController.java, HMSGUIInterface.java files), and add records using the following code:

```
 FileWriter tfw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true); 
                BufferedWriter tbw = new BufferedWriter(tfw);
                tbw.write(this.view.gettNumber() + "," + this.view.gettName() + "," +     this.view.gettDoctor() + "," + this.view.gettRoom());
                tbw.newLine();
                tbw.flush();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully added treatment!"); }
```

Please help on how I can add a reader as well, to display all the records from the text file to a table?

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in line with your MVC, you could create a `TableModel` which knew how to read a give patient record.

Personally though, I'd prefer to separate the management of the patient data from the view, so the view didn't care about where the data came from.

To this end, I would start by creating a `Patient` object and a `Treatment` object, these would hold the data in a self contained entity, making the management simpler...

You would need to read this data in and parse the results...

```
List<Treatment> treatments = new ArrayList<Treatment>(25);
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String text = null;
    while ((text = br.readline()) != null) {
        String parts[] = text.split(",");
        Treatmeant treament = new Treatment(parts[0],
            parts[1],
            parts[2],
            parts[3]);
        treatments.add(treament);
    }
} // Handle exception as required...
```

I'd wrap this into a `readTreatments` method in some utility class to make it easier to use...

Around about here, I'd be considering using a stand alone database or even an XML document, but that's just me.

Once you have this, you can design a `TableModel` to support it...

```
public class TreatmentTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    protected static final String[] COUMN_NAMES = {
        "Treatment-Number", 
        "Treatment-Name",
        "Doctor-in-charge",
        "Room-No",
    };
    protected static final Class[] COLUMN_CLASSES = new Class[]{
        Integer.class, 
        String.class,
        Doctor.class,
        Integer.class,
    };
    private List<Treatment> treatments;

    public TreatmentTableModel() {
        this.treatments = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public TreatmentTableModel(List<Treatment> treatments) {
        this.treatments = new ArrayList<>(treatments);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return treatments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return COUMN_NAMES[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return COLUMN_CLASSES[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Treatment treatment = treatments.get(rowIndex);
        Object value = null;
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                value = treatment.getNumber();
                break;
            case 1:
                value = treatment.getName();
                break;
            case 2:
                value = treatment.getDoctor();
                break;
            case 3:
                value = treatment.getRoomNumber();
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

Then you simply apply it to what ever `JTable` you need...

```
private JTable treatments;

//...
treatments = new JTable(new TreatmentTableModel());
add(new JScrollPane(treatments));
```

Then, we you need to, you would load the `List` of `Treatment`s and apply it to the table...

```
File file = new File("...");
treatments.setModel(new TreatmentTableModel(TreatmentUtilities.readTreatments(file)));
```

Comment: thank you... the part which confuses me is where to add each piece of code. which part do i add in the Model, which part in the view and which part in the controller?

Comment: Think about it.  You "model" will need to provide information to the view about what to show, so it needs to provide some means by which the view can obtain the current `Treatment` `List`.  The "controller" knows when the user has changed the view (or wants to change the view), so it needs to tell the "model" when to load new data OR load new data itself and pass that information to the "model". The model would then trigger an update which would alert the view to reload the `JTable`'s model with the new values which have been loaded

Comment: i don't understand! there is so much code already i am getting everything mixed up :(

Comment: Without a greater understanding of your over code, it's difficult to make recommendations.  If you intend to replace your current view with the `JTable`, then you need to provide some means by which that view can generate the (child) table model. This would suggest that your current model needs to provide some means to provide a `List` of `Treatement`s...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs for the table, you can look at using the `DefaultTableModel` and populating your data using that model. The downside to that is, you may want special capability from your table, like not being able to edit cells, store more than strings, etc... in which case you might look in to extending `AbstractTableModel` and defining your own behavior for the model.

A simple thing to do would be to start with the default model and expand on that.

```
String[] myColumns = {"Treatment-Number","Treatment-Name", "Doctor-in-charge", "Room-No"};
// init a model with no data and the specified column names
DefaultTableModel myModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[myList.size()][4](), myColumns);

// assuming you have a list of lists...
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for (ArrayList<Object> list : myList) {
    for ( Object o : list ) {
        myModel.setValueAt(o, i, j);  // set the value at cell i,j to o
        j++;
    }
    i++;
} 

JTable myTable = new JTable(myModel);  // make a new table with the specified data model
// ... do other stuff with the table
```

If you want to access the table data, you use `myTable.getModel()` and update the data. This will automatically update the view of the table (completing the MVC connection)

Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#simple) for more info on using tables.

Comment: The table model _is_ your model. The view is the JTable, and the controller will be where you add this code (or the code that will have your "view" class create the table model). It will really depend on how you've broken out your code, but the class that creates and updates your UI elements will be where you'd likely put the creation and update methods for passing/getting data in the table, and your controller for processing the events from the user and updating the table model.

Comment: i still don't understand! there is so much code already i am getting everything mixed up :(

Comment: Sounds like you might not have a strong enough grasp on MVC to apply any advice on this problem without getting confused. Try taking a look at [this tutorial](http://www.newthinktank.com/2013/02/mvc-java-tutorial/) and see if that clears anything up for you. Without seeing your code, it's difficult to help further...